# Scaling and loading the image from res\drawable-hdpi folder

Tags: android

In my Android app, To avoid the OOM (bitmap Out of Memory error), I am scaling and loading the image from the assets folder. I have some of my images in res\drawable-hdpi folder. Is there is any I can scale and load it as I do for the images in assets folder ?

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public  Drawable getAssetImage(String filename) throws IOException {

        int dWidth,dHeight;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        if (  Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) < 13 ) { 
             dWidth  = display.getWidth();
             dHeight = display.getHeight();  
        } else {  
              Point size = new Point();
              display.getSize(size);
              dWidth  = size.x;
              dHeight = size.y; 
       }    

        AssetManager assets = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream buffer = null;
        try {
            buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open(filename + ".png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        options.inPurgeable = true;    

        if (tabletSize) { 

        } else { 

            int tempSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, (int)dWidth, (int)dHeight);   

            Log.i("ClassicalMemoryGame", "dWidth  " + dWidth );
            Log.i("ClassicalMemoryGame", "dHeight " + dHeight );  
            Log.i("ClassicalMemoryGame", "sample size - "   + tempSampleSize );

            if (tempSampleSize > 1) {  
                options.inSampleSize = tempSampleSize;
            } 
        } 
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, options);
        Bitmap finalImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, (int) dWidth, (int) dHeight, true);

        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),finalImage);  

        return d;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to do so:

```
public static Bitmap decodeScaledSampleBitmap(Resources res,
    int resourceId,int width, int height)
{

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resourceId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,
    width, height);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resourceId, options),
    width, height, true);

return b;
}
```